Unable to push my project on my Github Repo
i am facing a problem when trying to push my local project on my github repository .When typing git push and get the error `fatal: The current branch main has no upstream branch.
To push the current branch and set the remote as upstream, use
git push --set-upstream origin main

To have this happen automatically for branches without a tracking
upstream, see 'push.autoSetupRemote' in 'git help config'.
` .How could i solve it ?

did you try git push --set-upstream origin main ?

first time you call this, second - just git push

@AntonBogdanov here is what i get:  git push --set-upstream origin main
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/warrior226/Jetpack-Compose-Tutorial.git/' not found

does repo exist?

@AntonBogdanov yes , the repo exists
